# Limit number of visible items in dropdown

Tags: react-select

I need to limit the number of visible options displayed in the react-select dropdown panel.

At the moment it shows around 9 items but I need that limited to 5. I'm not sure how to go about making changes to the dropdown.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: You can filter your `options` array to whatever number of elements you want to show, before actually assigning to `Select`.

Comment: I don't want to filter the options. I just want to limit the visible ones displayed in the dropdown panel. At the moment the dropdown panel is too large, I need less items visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out by overriding core component styles. It was just a case of finding which component rendered the styles I was interested in.

In this case it was the `menuList` component that controlled the visible items in the dropdown. To override the component styles this is what I used:

```
const selectStyles = {
  menuList: styles => {
    console.log('menuList:', styles);
    return {
      ...styles,
      maxHeight: 136
    };
  }
};

return (
  <Select
    value={selectVal}
    onChange={updateVal}
    options={options}
    styles={selectStyles}
  />
);
```

I found it very useful to `console.log` out the component styles to see what styles are available for a particular component as well as the default values used.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use this [react-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown-select) library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown-select?

This library has options attributes. Which are the options the user can select. For this answer. You can put 5 items in options like follow.

```js
const options = [
  {key: '1', value: 'first'},
  {key: '2', value: 'two'},
  {key: '3', value: 'three'},
  {key: '4', value: 'four'},
  {key: '5', value: 'five'}
];

<react-dropdown-selecte options={options} />
```

Comment: This library also using options as an attribute to save list value you can use. Ex:
`<Select
        value={1}
        options={options}
      />
`. Follow the post I have posted a above to fix.

Comment: I don't want to filter the items, just the visible ones in the dropdown. At the moment the dropdown panel is too large, I need less items visible.