# How to Fix width of the react select search box

Tags: reactjs, react-select-search

I have tried almost all answers but that is not working to get the width of react select fix sized.
It keeps on increasing as soon as I select options. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.
I need to show max two options selected in one line. The react-select version I am using is 5.4.0

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: check this question here: [Limit number of visible items in dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57575768/limit-number-of-visible-items-in-dropdown)

Comment: @HarounDarjaj I referred that, using this solution it is limiting length and height of dropdown options.
But I want this increasing select box to be fixed. Suppose first two options I selected then next selected option should go down.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a max-width property to the select tag. It will extend until it reached that amount specified in the max-width.